# Does a PAG (partial ancestral graph) have almost directed cycles with circular endpoints?

Tags: causality, graphical-model, causal-diagram

In https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/zhang08a/zhang08a.pdf, a Maximal Ancestral Graph (MAG) is defined as:

```
a mixed-edge graph that:

i) does not contain any directed or almost directed cycles (ancestral) and 
ii) there is no inducing path between any two non-adjacent vertices (maximal).
```

An almost directed cycle would be $X\to Z\to Y$ with also $X\leftrightarrow Y$ in a MAG. However, in a PAG, I'm wondering if an "almost directed cycle" with circular endpoints is possible.

$$X\,\circ\!\!\to Z\,\circ\!\!\to Y\,\circ\!\!\to X.$$

A PAG is a Markov equivalence class of MAGs as defined in the paper linked above.

[image: PAG definition]

Comment: For the purposes of this post, could you please define two things: what is a PAG? And what does the notation $X\,\circ\!\!\to Y$ mean? There are one or two posts on this site concerning MAGs - I don't know if they would be helpful or not.